# Any way to refactor this code smaller?

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I did a pretty good hack and slash on the original code, but I'm not seeing any way to condense this smaller without farming the checks into another file in a module.  The regex text is different for each when/x/, so they can't be combined any further that I can think of

```
    case state
      when /OH|PA|MN/
        if @browser.text.include?("My text")
            raise "x" unless /foo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y" unless /foo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z" unless /foo3/.match(@browser.text)
        else
            raise "x1" unless /foofoo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y1" unless /foofoo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z1" unless /foofoo3/.match(@browser.text)
        end
      when /IL|VA/
        if @browser.text.include?("My text")
            raise "x" unless /foo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y" unless /foo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z" unless /foo3/.match(@browser.text)
        else
            raise "x1" unless /foofoo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y1" unless /foofoo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z1" unless /foofoo3/.match(@browser.text)
        end
      when /WI|SC|TN|IN|IA/
        if @browser.text.include?("My text")
            raise "x" unless /foo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y" unless /foo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z" unless /foo3/.match(@browser.text)
        else
            raise "x1" unless /foofoo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y1" unless /foofoo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z1" unless /foofoo3/.match(@browser.text)
        end
      when /SC/
        if @browser.text.include?("My text")
            raise "x" unless /foo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y" unless /foo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z" unless /foo3/.match(@browser.text)
        else
            raise "x1" unless /foofoo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y1" unless /foofoo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z1" unless /foofoo3/.match(@browser.text)
        end
      when /GA/
        if @browser.text.include?("My text")
            raise "x" unless /foo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y" unless /foo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z" unless /foo3/.match(@browser.text)
        else
            raise "x1" unless /foofoo/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "y1" unless /foofoo2/.match(@browser.text)
            raise "z1" unless /foofoo3/.match(@browser.text)
        end
      else
        raise "Not a valid state"
      end
```

Comment: Is all this seriously to choose what error to return???

Comment: You may want to post this kind of question on the Code Review Stack Exchange. But if you're getting 4 downvotes, you may be doing something else wrong as well.

Comment: I think the folks on Code Review would throw it back at us. :-)

Comment: Actually it returns an error on each match so the user running the test(a non developer) gets an error code specific to what specific line in the text is wrong in for that test case.. there are 5 separate possible outcomes for a test case dependent on which state the test case is run against

Answer (score 1):

i assume that its differnt in your real code so that you couldnt do

```
if state =~/OH|PA|MN|IL|VA|WI|SC|TN|IN|IA|SC|GA/
    if @browser.text.include?("My text")
        raise "x" unless /foo/.match(@browser.text)
        raise "y" unless /foo2/.match(@browser.text)
        raise "z" unless /foo3/.match(@browser.text)
    else
        raise "x1" unless /foofoo/.match(@browser.text)
        raise "y1" unless /foofoo2/.match(@browser.text)
        raise "z1" unless /foofoo3/.match(@browser.text)
    end
else
    raise "Not a valid state"
end
```

because right now you can. So if you really wanted an answer why did you post fake code that can be easily reduced?

Comment: I posted the fake code because the real code is proprietary business language and I didn't want to risk losing my job..

Comment: Haha, i understand, but if for each `when` you execute the same block of code then, there is no reason to have a case statement at all. IF the code is proprietary then don't post it, but unless you can do a little better than this all you will get is unhelpful answers, be misunderstood, and lots of down-votes

Answer (score 1):

```
raise "Not a valid state" unless %w[OH PA MN IL VA WI SC TN IN IA SC GA].include?(state)
if @browser.text.include?("My text")
  raise case @browser.text
  when /foo/; "x"
  when /foo2/; "y"
  when /foo3/; "z"
  end
else
  raise case @browser.text
  when /foofoo/; "x1"
  when /foofoo2/; "y1"
  when /foofoo3/; "z1"
  end
end
```